# Can i use reactive forms in angular with an input field that is treated seperatly when stored and populated than the rest input fields?

Tags: angular, dynamic, model, angular-reactive-forms, two-way-binding

Currently i an using template driven form and [(ngModel)]

I have a product model shown bellow..

```ts
    export interface Product {

    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    key: string;
    description: string;
    
}
```

I also keep in a seperate place in the database how many units of the product are available..
Currently storing happens by two separate services..

when storing / updating / Creating i use the same form.

below i provide the productForm component..

```ts
import { QuantityAvailableService } from './../../quantity-available.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from './../../product.service';
import { CategoryService } from './../../category.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})

export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  
  categories$: Observable<{}>;
  product: any  = {};
  stockQuantity: any = {};
  id;


  constructor(
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private quantityAvailableService: QuantityAvailableService,
    private router: Router
    ) {
    
    this.categories$ = this.categoryService.getAll().snapshotChanges();

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.id) {
      this.quantityAvailableService.get(this.id).subscribe(data => this.stockQuantity = data);
      this.productService.get(this.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(p => {
      return this.product = p;
     });
  }}

  ngOnInit() { }


  save(product) {
    if (this.id) {

      this.productService.update(this.id, product);
      this.quantityAvailableService.update(this.id, this.stockQuantity);

     } else {
       this.productService.create(product);
       this.quantityAvailableService.create(this.id, this.stockQuantity);
      }

    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }



  delete() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?')) {  return; }

    this.productService.delete(this.id);
    this.quantityAvailableService.remove(this.id);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);

  }
}
```

```html
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
          
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id ="title" type="text" 
                class="form-control" required>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
              Title is required.
            </div>
         </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="price">Price</label>
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
              <input #price="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.price" name="price" id ="price" type="number" 
                 class="form-control" required [min]="0"> 
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
                <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
         
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quantityAvailable">Quantity available</label>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input #quantityAvailable="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="stockQuantity" name="quantityAvailable" id 
               ="quantityAvailable" type="number" class="form-control" required [min]="0"> 
            </div>
           <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="quantityAvailable.touched && 
                 quantityAvailable.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="quantityAvailable.errors.required">Quantity available is required.</div>
              <div *ngIf="quantityAvailable.errors.min">Quantity available should be 0 or higher.</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="category">Category</label>
              <select #category="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" id ="category" 
                 class="form-control"  required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.payload.val().name">
                  {{ c.payload.val().name }}
                </option>
                </select>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
                Category is required.
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="description">Description</label>
              <textarea rows="7" #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.description" 
               name="description" id ="description" class="form-control rounded-0" required></textarea>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="description.touched && description.invalid">
                description is required.
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
           <input #imageUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" id ="image" 
               type="text" class="form-control" required url>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">ImageUrl is required.</div>
              <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Please enter a valid URL</div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <product-card [product]="product" [showActions]="false"></product-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to create an input field that will store url addresses in an Array and update dynamicly that is check validity, store in an array (locally, not database) and display the value under the input field in a list and that is before submiting the form, by submiting it will store to database.

..so i am considering turning the form to reactive form so that i can dynamicly create my array..

..my problem is..

i have an input field that is not related to my product model and i need to populate it when updating the form,
i also need to have it required and react with the submit function of the form (disable the submit button),
lastly i need to store it in a different place than the product through a seperate service.

is it possible with reactive forms? any suggestions are welcome..

i have about a year experience in programming, i hope i am providing enough info..

Comment: i decited to abandom this practice because it introduces alot of unessesary code and work insead with the model of the project.  i also realized a bug with the approach i was trying to implement. I could not make the  Eliseo approach work however i believe that your best bet to approach this matter is @djangofan suggestion to use 2 form objects on your form, passed as FormArray.. it would look cleanner codewize.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Let's say I had a form that represented a Song object AND I have the following 2 methods on my `SongHandlerService` object.

```
updateSong(index: number, newSong: FormGroup) {
  const song = this.convertFormToSong(newSong.value);
  ...
{
```

In my form page, the submit button calls a method on the form page that in turn calls this `updateSong` method.

Now, the form can be broken into a raw type, like you see in the args to this method:

```
private convertFormToSong(rawSong: {owner: string, title: string, composer: string,
    key: string, data: string, meta: string, published: boolean}): Song {
    return new Song(rawSong.owner, rawSong.title, rawSong.composer,
      rawSong.key, JSON.parse(rawSong.data), JSON.parse(rawSong.meta), rawSong.published);
  }
```

As you can see, in this kind of method, when receiving the form object as a raw type, then we can restructure the form data any way we like after the data is passed out of the form.

NOTE: Another way to do this is to have 2 form objects on your form, passed as FormArray.  I have not tried that myself yet.

Comment: i see you are suggesting a layer of translation between the form and the rest of the app, so propably it needs one more function like `convertFormToSong()` when you are calling the form to update an already existing song and you have to feed the input fields. So if i want to extract/import a value from the song to direct it elsewere or i need to feed a value from else were to the form do i need to extraxt or feed the coresponding  raw data and meta data? If yes how do you extract those?

Comment: Yes, you have a good point.  I think you are understanding it ( you would need a `convertSongToFormLoadable` method).   My solution may not be the best  for your case but it works for me since the extra field on my form is a JSON object which loads up in the form field as a stringified JSON object.   So, if you have a more complex situation, look at the other answers here (or FormArray).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get another aproach. Well, you has two services, but you can has an unique object and an unique FormGroup.

It's only an idea, you can,e.g.

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
if (this.id) {
  fokJoin(
         this.productService.get(this.id),
         this.quantityAvailableService.get(this.id)
  ).subscribe(([product,quantity]=>{
    product.quantity=quantity; //<--add a new property to Quantity
    this.form=this.getFormGroup(product)
  )
}
else
    this.form=this.getFormGroup()

getFormGroup(product:any=null)
{
    product=product || {} as Product
    product.quantity=product.quantity || 0
    return new FormGroup({
       categoryService:new FormControl(product.categoryService,Validators.required)
       ...
       quantity:new FromControl(product.quantity)
    })
}
```

In save

```
save(form)
{
    if (form.valid)
    {
        const quantity=form.value.quantity;
        const product={...form.value};
        delete product.quantity;
        if (product.id) {
           this.productService.update(this.id, product);
           this.quantityAvailableService.update(this.id, this.stockQuantity);
       } else {
          this.productService.create(product);
          this.quantityAvailableService.create(this.id, this.stockQuantity);
       }
}
```

**Update** to make more "suitable" we can  extend the interface

```
export interface ProductExtend extends Product
{
  quantity:number;
}
```

or add a optionalProperty to our Product

```
export interface Product {
    title: string;
    ....
    quantity?:number;
}
```

We can also use map to out forkJoin to return an unique object

```
fokJoin([
         this.productService.get(this.id),
         this.quantityAvailableService.get(this.id)]
  ).pipe(map([product,quantity]:[Product:number])=>{
    product.quantity=quantity; //<--add a new property to Quantity
    return product;
  )
```

or

```
fokJoin([
         this.productService.get(this.id),
         this.quantityAvailableService.get(this.id)]
  ).pipe(map([product,quantity]:[Product:number])=>{
    return productExtend:ProductExtend={...product,quantity:quantity}
  )
```

NOTE: Always has a "dude", that is if I make the forkJoin in the component or create a new function in a service

NOTE2: to generate a formGroup I like the has a function getFormGroup that feed with data

```
getForm(data:Product=null):FormGroup
{
    data=data || {} as Product
    return new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(data.title,Validatros.required),
      price:new FormControl(data.price)
      ...
    });
}
```

Comment: fokJoin() is depreciated and it suggests to Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead. (more reading :))

Comment: after some reasearch you can use forkJoin passing an array of observables. so i did this: forkJoin ([ this.productService.get(this.id).pipe(take(1)), this.quantityAvailableService.get(this.id) ])
      .subscribe(([product, quantity]) => {product.quantityAvailable =quantity;} );  but compiler complains because it knows product model does not use quantity available

Comment: it  seems that you can select a control and patch a value directly to it. here is what i did: `this.quantityAvailableService.get(this.id).subscribe(data => this.form.controls["quantityAvailable"].patchValue(data)) ;`

Comment: I updated the answer if you want extends the interface or create an optional property. I'm in general prefer create a function that return a formControl